# Integration of Power Series. When is the Function in $L_1$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, power-series, lp-spaces

Suppose we are given a function $f$ in terms of its power series
\begin{align}
f(x)= \sum_{n+0}^\infty a_n x^n.
\end{align}
We assume that we know all $a_n$'s and $f$ has infinite radius of convergense.

Can we say based on $a_n$ if the function is integrable or not? That is if 
\begin{align}
\int_{\mathbb{R}} |f(x)| dx<\infty.
\end{align}

For example, if $a_n \ge 0$ then we have that
\begin{align}
f(x) \ge a_0+a_1 x,\  x >0 ,
\end{align}
and the function is not integrable.

> The case that I am interested is when $a_n$'s have alternating sign. 
>   Specifically, can we determine if the following $f(x)$ is integrable
>   \begin{align} f(x)= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\cos( \frac{\pi}{2}k)\
>  (k+1)^{\frac{k+1}{6}}}{k!} x^k. \end{align}

Here is the plot of $f(x)$ where the series was computed up to $N=600$. [image: Blues is the $f(x)$ and red is $\frac{sin(\pi/2 x)}{\pi/2 x}$]

where blue curve is $f(x)$ and red curve is $sinc(\pi/2 x)= \frac{\sin(\pi/2 x)}{\pi/2 x}$.

It seems that $f(x)$ has a tail that decays faster than $sinc(\pi/2 x)$.

Moreover, next we give a plot of $f(x) \cdot x$  and  $f(x) \cdot x^2$
[image]

where blue curve is $f(x) \cdot x$ and red curve is  $f(x) \cdot x^2$.

This seems to indicate that $f(x)$ decreases faster than $\frac{1}{x^2}$ which would imply that $f(x)$ is integrable.

Therefore, it would also be interesting to show that 
\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)=0,
\end{align}
which at this moment I do not know how to do.

Thanks you.

**Edit: **  Please see a possible solution via Mellin transform.

Comment: If the power series converges in all of $\mathbb{R}$, the function is analytic, so it should automatically be integrable, unless I'm being really stupid, which I conceivably might be.

Comment: @Daminark As I understand it the question is about when $\int_0^{\infty} f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x$ exists rather than whether $f$ might be pathologically unintegrable

Comment: Do you mean $|a_{n+1}| \ge |a_n|$?  That contradicts the "infinite radius of convergence" (unless they are all $0$).

Comment: If $a_n > 0$ for even $n$, $f(x) + f(-x) = 2 \sum_{n\ \text{even}} a_n x^n \ge a_2 x^2$ for $x > 0$, and $f(x)$ and $f(-x)$ can't both be integrable on $[0,\infty)$, and $f$ can't be integrable on $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael  Thanks. I modified my question with a specific example I had in mind.

Comment: @AlexM. Note that there is a division by $6$ in the exponent. So, the coefficient indeed go to zero.

Comment: sinc is **not** integrable, although its improper integral converges.   For integrability you'll want a decay better than the $1/|x|$ of sinc, maybe $1/|x|^p$ for some $p > 1$.  The picture might suggest that this is the case, but of course it's not a proof.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Yes, this what I was thinking too. The $sinc()$ is not integrable but since $f(x)$ decays faster than $sinc()$ there is hope that it might be integrable. However, I am not even sure where to start.

Comment: @RobertIsrael following up on you previous comment. It seems that $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) \cdot x^2 =0$  which suggests that $f(x)$ is integrable.

Comment: If that's true (which I'm not convinced of), then it is integrable.

Comment: I asked a similar question here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/916707/when-is-an-analytic-function-in-l2-bbb-r. It's a very challenging question, I gather.

Comment: The only idea I have is use Mellin's inversion theorem. Observe if $f(x) = \int_{\sigma - i \infty}^{\sigma+i\infty} \Gamma(z)\cos(-\pi/2 z)(-z+1)^{(1-z)/6}x^{-z}\,dz$. Your function decays if and only if this expression is valid when $0 < \sigma < 1$. I don't think this integral converges so 'm doubting your function converges.

Comment: BTW, this works only for $\int_0^\infty$.

Comment: @james.nixon I see that you trying to use Laplace transform somehow. Can you elaborate more on this?

Comment: @RobertIsrael Do you think showing $L_2$ instead of $L_1$ might be easier?

Comment: @boby Well if $f(x)$ is written as I wrote, and the expression converges (which actually it does, I forgot $z^z$ has the appropriate decay) then $\Gamma(z)\cos(-\pi/2z)(1-z)^{(1-z)/6}=\int_0^\infty f(x)x^{z-1}$ when $0 < \Re(z) < 1$, and $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \cos(\pi/2 k )(k+1)^{(k+1)/6}\frac{(-x)^n}{n!}$ (notice the negative sign). This follows by some residue calculus that is well out there in the literature. This also ensures that $f(-x)x \to 0$, With some work you can show this function is in $L^1(0,\infty)$--it shouldn't take much. It's symmetric so it's in $L^1(-\infty,\infty)$.

Comment: @james.nixon Your approach seems interesting. Would you consider putting it as an answer with some details?

Comment: @boby Yeah sure, I don't have time at the moment, but I'll make it an answer and add some references and fill in a few details later.

Comment: See if these [search results](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=integrable%2C%20%24f(x)%3D%5Csum_%7Bn%3D0%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7Da_nx%5En%24&p=1) help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To start consider mellin's inversion theorem.

Mellin's inversion theorem can be stated as, if

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\sigma - i\infty}^{\sigma + i\infty}F(z)x^{-z}\,dz$$

Assuming everything is convergent, $0 < \sigma < 1$, $F$ holomorphic, then

$$F(z) = \int_0^\infty f(x)x^{z-1}\,dx$$

for $0 < \Re(z) < 1$

Ramanujan's master theorem gives us a really beautiful result based off this. If $z\Gamma(-z)g(z) \to 0$ as $z \to \infty$ when $|\arg(z)| < \pi/2$ and $g(z) = O(e^{\tau|\Im(z)|})$ for $\tau < \pi/2$, then

Ramanujan's Master theorem says

$$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty g(n)\frac{(-x)^n}{n!} = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\sigma - i \infty}^{\sigma+ i \infty} \Gamma(z)g(-z)x^{-z}\,dz$$

If you need more justification of this fact look at Ramanujan's master theorem, even wikipedia has something on this. There are a few ways of stating this, but the version I'm using is perfectly valid.

What is great is that

$$\int_0^\infty |f(x)| x^{-\sigma}\,dx < \infty$$

Which is another consequence of Mellin's inversion theorem.

Now your function $F(z) = \cos(\pi/2 z)(z+1)^{(z+1)/6}$ satisfies these bounds. It is rather trivial to show this, if need be I'll edit this in. By the above

$$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \cos(\pi/2n)(n+1)^{(n+1)/6}\frac{(-x)^n}{n!}$$

satisfies for $0 < \Re(z) < 1$

$$\int_0^\infty f(x)x^{z-1}\,dx = \Gamma(z)F(z)$$

Therefore off the start, your function $f$ is in a weighted $L^{1}$ space (with weight $x^{-\sigma}$ (this is also part of Mellin's inversion theorem).  All the odd powers disappear, meaning the function is symmetric about zero. Therefore

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty |f(x)|x^{-\sigma}\,dx < \infty$$

for all $ 0 < \sigma < 1$. I'll leave it to you to show the subtleties required in making it $L^1$. If you can't, I'll show it .

Comment: I just wanted to break up your argument into logical steps. Let me know if the following is correct.   The steps are:   1) Identify that  $g(z)=\cos(\pi/2 z) (z+1)^{(z+1)/6}$ has the property that $z \Gamma(-z) g(z) \to 0$ as $z \to \infty$.     2)   By Ramanujan's master theorem this implies that the function $f(z)= \sum_{n=0}^\infty g(n) \frac{(-x)^n}{n!}$  can be expressed as $f(z)= \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\sigma-i \infty}^{\sigma+i \infty} \Gamma(z) g(-z) x^{-z} dz$.    3)  This is the step I am confused about. How do we now know that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty |f(x)| x^{-\sigma} dx<\infty$???

Comment: @Boby Am I being stupid or is this just because $f(z)$ is the Mellin transform of $\Gamma(z)g(-z)$, so $\int_0^\infty f(x)x^{z-1}\,dx = \Gamma(z)F(z)$?

Comment: @Anon I am not sure. I guess the claims is that if $f(z)$ is Mellin transform of $\Gamma(z)g(-z)$ then $f(z)$ satisfies $\int_{0}^\infty |f(z)|  x^{-\sigma} dx<\infty$. But I don't know where is this comming from?

Comment: @Boby I think it's from [Mellin's inversion theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mellin_inversion_theorem) which he mentioned. I think that will give you his second-last formula (by applying the inversion theorem to his third formula which has the form of an inverse [Mellin transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mellin_transform)), which (with what he says at the beginning) I think gives the last formula.

Comment: Yeah, it's all because of Mellin's inversion theorem.  $\int_0^\infty f(x)x^{z-1}\,dx = \Gamma(z)F(z)$, which isn't trvial to prove. If I showed the whole thing it would take like 5 pages. Just look up Mellin's inversion theorem, and  Ramanujan's master theorem. Both of these results should clear up your confusion.

Comment: @boby That's essentially correct. The first step also requires an exponential bound as $\Im(z) \to \infty$ though. The 3rd step and the 2nd step are both non trivial. Ramanujan's master theorem, and Mellin's inversion theorem show this fact though.

Comment: @james.nixon Sorry about this. But I still have a few questions. I hope you don't mind. When you say: If $z\Gamma(-z)g(z) \to 0$ as $z \to \infty$ when $|\arg(z)| < \pi/2$ and $g(z) = O(e^{\tau|\Im(z)|})$ for $\tau < \pi/2$, then

$$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty g(n)\frac{(-x)^n}{n!} = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\sigma - i \infty}^{\sigma+ i \infty} \Gamma(z)g(-z)x^{-z}\,dz$$    Is this the Mellin inversion theorem or  Ramanujan's master theorem?

Comment: This is Ramanujan's master theorem. It can be stated a few ways, I just chose this way of stating it. If need be I can give you a rough contour integration argument using residue calculus to show this result, it's rather straight forward. Then, Mellin's inversion theorem is the theorem that guarantees $\int_0^\infty f(x)x^{z-1}\,dx = \Gamma(z)g(-z)$ (which is also part of Ramanujan's master theorem).

Comment: @james.nixon Thank you. This is what I was confused about.  Because the  Ramanujan's master theorem on Wikipedia and Wolfram says if $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty g(n) \frac{x^n}{n!}$ then $\int x^{z-1} f(x) dx =\Gamma(z) g(-z)$. At the beginning of you question can you indent which version of theorems are you using?

Comment: Yeah sure, I'll edit it.

Comment: @james.nixon   Can you also clarify how $\int_0^\infty  f(x) x^{z-1} dx=\Gamma(z)F(z)$ implies that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty |f(x)| x^{-\sigma} dx <\infty$??

Comment: @boby, this is also part of Mellin's inversion theorem. The integral converges absolutely. Just search up a well stated version of Mellin's inversion theorem for a good reference. The proof uses the fourier transform and would take a lot to show. And since the function is even, it converges all over $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @james.nixon It seems like you have some, experience, with Meillin transform. Maybe  you will be interested in the following question.

Comment: @Boby Sure, I'll take a look. Just post it.

Comment: @james.nixon http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2092151/inverse-mellin-transform-of-ft-2-fracit16-frac-gamma-left-frac?noredirect=1#comment4300083_2092151